# How to make the Image black and white?

Tags: java, gwt

I have created Image. How to convert color Image to black&white. For example, on mouse over it.

Comment: These classes are not available (client-side)
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create another image in black and white server side (or using an image editing program if the image isn't dynamic) and swap out the color one for b&w on mouse over.

**edit**

Then just just set the opacity using css: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

Comment: I'm trying to make a menu-item disabled (http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1649). But my menu-item contains "random" Image.

Answer (score 3):

First open it in a decent image editor, convert it to *grayscale* (I assume that you want more colors than black and white ;) ), save it in the webapplication.

Then, on the mouseover just call some JavaScript function which changes the `src` of the HTML `<img>` element to point to the URL of the grayscale image instead.

Basic kickoff example:

```
<img src="color.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='blackwhite.jpg'">
```

Comment: It's been a while since I used GWT, but you can probably do this without "resorting" to Javascript (`Image.addMouseListener()` and `Image.setURL()`).

Comment: Exists a way that button becomes disabled and its image converted to b&w. So we can use one Image

Comment: No. You may consider merging the two images in a CSS sprite instead and use `background-position`. This way the user doesn't need to wait for the b/w image to get loaded. Also see http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites

Answer (score 0):

The [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/desaturate/) JS Image Manipulation library has this feature, which you can call via JSNI.

There's also [this script](http://elouai.com/javascript/javascript-image-grayscale.php) which appears to only work in IE using proprietary Microsoft magic.

But honestly, just generate a desaturated image for every image you want on the server-side, and swap them out using JS/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
  transition: filter .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* Ch 23+, Saf 6.0+, BB 10.0+ */
  filter: grayscale(0%); /* FF 35+ */
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Ch 23+, Saf 6.0+, BB 10.0+ */
  filter: grayscale(100%); /* FF 35+ */
}
```

The Black and White effect is achieved with the grayscale value for the filter property. grayscale(100%) corresponds to Black and White and grayscale(0%) corresponds to full colors.
The -webkit-filter prefix is necessary for that property
The smooth animation is achieved with the transition property